# What functions can read-once branching programs compute?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity

Barrington's Theorem gives us that polynomial size and bounded width Branching programs can compute exactly functions in $NC_1$, are there any results known about read-once BPs - bounded width and polynomial size?

Comment: Small correction: polysize branching programs exist for all languages in L/poly (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L/poly). Barrington's theorem says something different (about fixed width BP).

Comment: Do the results in Section 7 of A. A. Razborov, [Lower bounds for deterministic and nondeterministic branching programs](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/files/fct.pdf) (Proc. FCT, 1991) help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Barrington's theorem shows that **polynomial size, bounded width** branching programs compute exactly the languages in $NC^1$. (Specifically, he shows this for branching programs with width at least 5, and a later result shows that 5 is necessary to capture $NC^1$). However, it's easy to see that **any** function is computable by an exponential size, read-once branching program (just take a decision tree which branches on every variable and outputs the truth-table of the function). If we wanted to focus on, say, polynomial size, read-once branching programs, then nothing is really known in terms of a standard complexity class. The "bounded replication" classes of branching programs (i.e. branching programs with a restriction on the number of times variables appear) don't really offer themselves well to such characterizations. Rather, the complexity classes for which we **do** have branching program characterizations are natural, given the model (i.e. like $L/poly$) or given via an algebraic approach, like Barrington's theorem or related results (e.g. [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=48014.63138)).

There is an [excellent book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-24508-4/page/1) by Jukna which studies different types of branching programs in depth.